# Problems installing R packages from source in RStudio - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, rstudio, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running R and RStudio on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit, and am trying to do clustering analysis, though I think my error is not specific to this package...  But when I try to install the package '**ClusterR**' from CRAN, I get the following error.

```
> install.packages("ClusterR")
Installing package into ‘/home/daniel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘tiff’, ‘OpenImageR’, ‘gmp’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tiff_0.1-5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 28925 bytes (28 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 28 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/OpenImageR_1.0.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 802641 bytes (783 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 783 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gmp_0.5-13.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 131321 bytes (128 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 128 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ClusterR_1.0.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 916490 bytes (895 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 895 KB

* installing *source* package ‘tiff’ ...
** package ‘tiff’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c common.c -o common.o
In file included from common.c:1:0:
common.h:5:18: fatal error: tiff.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:159: recipe for target 'common.o' failed
make: *** [common.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘tiff’
* removing ‘/home/daniel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/tiff’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tiff’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘gmp’ ...
** package ‘gmp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
creating cache ./config.cache
checking for __gmpz_ui_sub in -lgmp... no
configure: error: GNU MP not found, or not 4.1.4 or up, see http://gmplib.org
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘gmp’
* removing ‘/home/daniel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/gmp’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gmp’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘tiff’ is not available for package ‘OpenImageR’
* removing ‘/home/daniel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/OpenImageR’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘OpenImageR’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘OpenImageR’, ‘gmp’ are not available for package ‘ClusterR’
* removing ‘/home/daniel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/ClusterR’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ClusterR’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpuIo1WM/downloaded_packages’
```

And indeed, if I try installing just the package '**tiff**' I get the same error, distilled here:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/daniel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tiff_0.1-5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 28925 bytes (28 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 28 KB

* installing *source* package ‘tiff’ ...
** package ‘tiff’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c common.c -o common.o
In file included from common.c:1:0:
common.h:5:18: fatal error: tiff.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:159: recipe for target 'common.o' failed
make: *** [common.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘tiff’
* removing ‘/home/daniel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/tiff’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tiff’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpuIo1WM/downloaded_packages’
```

I'm still somewhat of a coding newbie, both with R and Ubuntu, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here?  I have a feeling that I'm missing some dependency/library in Ubuntu that is needed for installing from source this way in R but I'm not sure what?  And I haven't had trouble installing other packages from source, including even other packages loaded with '**ClusterR**'.

I have GCC Fortran installed, terminal code listed here:

```
daniel@fulgur-desktop:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-debian/2012-November/002011.html) helps

Comment: It seems that missing [`libtiff-devel`](https://github.com/aoles/EBImage/issues/2) may be the problem.

Comment: akrun- I did not see that previous query, thank you! It, along with Konrad and beigel's answers, helped me learn what I need to do to make these packages work.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

R packages often has external system dependencies that usually cannot be installed through R. If you check the [CRAN package docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tiff/index.html) for the tiff package it mentions tiff and jpeg libraries are required. Anyway, looking around on Ubuntu package list and making a search for [tiff](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tiff&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all) leads to the `libtiff5-dev` package. Run

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev
```

And you should be fine. As a heads up, for installing system requirements for an R package, you usually want to install the version with `-dev` at the end.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know which package I needed, but even more- thank you for explaining how I can determine that information!  `libtiff5-dev` did indeed allow me to install the _tiff_ package, but then after that _gmp_ still didn't work.  So I checked the _gmp_ requirements and saw I had to install it in Ubuntu- looked it up in the Ubuntu package list and found and installed `libgmp-dev`.  Now _ClusterR_ installed and is working perfectly!  Thank you, again!

Answer (score 0):

For mac, you can use brew:

```
brew install -v libtiff
```

And then I got the following error when installing the package image in R:

```
configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted.
```

That is solved installing X11 for mac: https://www.xquartz.org/index.html